# How do I vectorize this double for loop in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have some Python / Numpy code that is running slow and I think it is because of the use of a double for loop. Here is the code.

```
def heat(D,u0,q,tdim):
    xdim = np.size(u0)
    Z = np.zeros([xdim,tdim])
    Z[:,0]=u0;
    for i in range(1,tdim):
        for j in range (1,xdim-1):
            Z[j,i]=Z[j,i-1]+D*q*(Z[j-1,i-1]-2*Z[j,i-1]+Z[j+1,i-1])
    return Z
```

I am trying to remove the double for loop and vectorize Z. Here is my attempt.

```
def heat(D,u0,q,tdim):
    xdim = np.size(u0)
    Z = np.zeros([xdim,tdim])
    Z[:,0]=u0;
    Z[1:,1:-1]=Z[1:-1,:-1]+D*q*(Z[:-2,:-1]-2*Z[1:-1,:-1]+Z[2:,:-1])
    return Z
```

This doesn't work - I get the following error:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (24,73) (23,74)
```

So somewhere in trying to vectorize Z, I messed up. Can you please help me spot my error?

Comment: When I have those kind of errors I always try to print out the `len` of more or less everything. Check if the length of `Z[1:,1:-1]` is correct, and so on.

Comment: Did you try to profile your code with cProfile or something? I think you should identify your real bottleneck first.

Comment: The bottleneck is in the call to heat, which takes 99.9% of the program time. So yes, this is where I need to be optimizing and I have read that vectorizing will speed up my code greatly. I'm just off by 1 on the dimensions :/

Comment: @user1493692, sorry its not that trivial to optimize directly (afterall). The for loop relies on previously changed values (is this wanted?), this will not happen if vectorized like this, before doing bigger hacks its, easier to use cython if you don't mind the small compiling step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot vectorize that diffusion calculation in the time dimension of the problem, that still requires a loop. The only obvious optimization here is to replace the Laplacian calculation with a call to the `numpy.diff` function (which is precompiled C), so your heat equation solver becomes:

```
def heat(D,u0,q,tdim): 
    xdim = np.size(u0) 
    Z = np.zeros([xdim,tdim]) 
    Z[:,0]=u0; 

    for i in range(1,tdim): 
        Z[1:-1,i]=Z[1:-1,i-1] + D*q*np.diff(Z[:,i-1], 2)

    return Z
```

For non-trivial spatial sizes you should see considerable speed up.

Comment: I'm trying to use http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html as a guide, where they vectorize a double for loop of what looks a lot similar to mine. What does `D*q*np.diff(Z[:,i-1], 2)` actually take place of in my original code.

Comment: The second difference calculated with `diff` replaces the inner loop over `Z[j-1,i-1]-2*Z[j,i-1]+Z[j+1,i-1])`. The blog post you refer to isn't vectorizing a loop like yours, despite the superficial similarities.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to remove both for loops as calculating column i depends on column i-1 which (in your second bit of code) is just zeros except for the first column.

What you could do is:

```
def heat(D,u0,q,tdim):
    xdim = np.size(u0)
    Z = np.zeros([xdim,tdim])
    Z[:,0]=u0;
    for i in range(1,tdim):
        Z[1:-1,i] = Z[1:-1,i-1] + D*q*(Z[:-2,i-1] - 2*Z[1:-1,i-1] + Z[2:,i-1])
    return Z
```

To get back to your code:
You are filling Z[1,1:-1] with (first term only) Z[1:-1,:-1]. The mismatch in shape is readily apparent here.

Disregarding the second index (as you will have to loop anyway), your vectorized solution uses a different assumption than the non-vectorized approach: in the first version you have one side u0 (Z[:,0]) and two sides 0 (Z[0,:] and Z[-1,:]) while in the vectorized solution you do try to set Z[-1,:] to something other than 0 by filling Z[1:,i]. Which situation are you trying to simulate?!